# autolayout-conform UILabel with vertical text (objC or Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, autolayout, uilabel

How would I create an UIView / UILabel with vertical text flow which would look like the red view of this example screen?

[image: view with vertical text]

I have read about view.transform = CGAffineTransform(... which allows for easy rotation, BUT it would break the auto-layout constraints.

I would be happy to use a third-party library, but I cannot find any.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try to describe in detail what you want to do and show what you've **tried** that didn't give you the desired results (with images, if that helps to clarify).

Comment: you're right. "vertical" can be ambiguous. The example screen should clarify the problem.

Comment: Hmmm… I remember posting a solution for this some time back. I should be able to find it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform):

> In iOS 8.0 and later, the transform property does not affect Auto Layout. Auto layout calculates a view’s alignment rectangle based on its untransformed frame.

So, to get transformed views to "play nice" with auto layout, we need to - in effect - tell constraints to use the opposite axis.

For example, if we embed a `UILabel` in a `UIView` and rotate the label 90-degrees, we want to constrain the "container" view's **Width** to the label's **Height** and its **Height** to the label's **Width**.

Here's a sample `VerticalLabelView` view subclass:

```
class VerticalLabelView: UIView {
    
    public var numberOfLines: Int = 1 {
        didSet {
            label.numberOfLines = numberOfLines
        }
    }
    public var text: String = "" {
        didSet {
            label.text = text
        }
    }
    
    // vertical and horizontal "padding"
    //  defaults to 16-ps (8-pts on each side)
    public var vPad: CGFloat = 16.0 {
        didSet {
            h.constant = vPad
        }
    }
    public var hPad: CGFloat = 16.0 {
        didSet {
            w.constant = hPad
        }
    }
    
    // because the label is rotated, we need to swap the axis
    override func setContentHuggingPriority(_ priority: UILayoutPriority, for axis: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis) {
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(priority, for: axis == .horizontal ? .vertical : .horizontal)
    }
    
    // this is just for development
    //  show/hide border of label
    public var showBorder: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            label.layer.borderWidth = showBorder ? 1 : 0
            label.layer.borderColor = showBorder ? UIColor.red.cgColor : UIColor.clear.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    public let label = UILabel()
    
    private var w: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var h: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var mh: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        addSubview(label)
        label.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // rotate 90-degrees
        let angle = .pi * 0.5
        label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
        
        // so we can change the "padding" dynamically
        w = self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.heightAnchor, constant: hPad)
        h = self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.widthAnchor, constant: vPad)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            w, h,
            
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

I've added a few properties to allow the view to be treated like a label, so we can do:

```
let v = VerticalLabelView()

// "pass-through" properties
v.text = "Some text which will be put into the label."
v.numberOfLines = 0

// directly setting properties
v.label.textColor = .red
```

This could, of course, be extended to "pass through" all label properties we need to use so we wouldn't need to reference the `.label` directly.

This `VerticalLabelView` can now be used much like a normal `UILabel`.

Here are two examples - they both use this `BaseVC` to setup the views:

```
class BaseVC: UIViewController {
    
    let greenView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()
    let normalLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    
    let lYellow: VerticalLabelView = {
        let v = VerticalLabelView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    
    let lRed: VerticalLabelView = {
        let v = VerticalLabelView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    
    let lBlue: VerticalLabelView = {
        let v = VerticalLabelView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.8, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        v.numberOfLines = 1
        return v
    }()
    
    let container: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let strs: [String] = [
            "Multiline Vertical Text",
            "Vertical Text",
            "Overflow Vertical Text",
        ]
        
        // default UILabel
        normalLabel.text = "Regular UILabel wrapping text"
        // add the normal label to the green view
        greenView.addSubview(normalLabel)
        
        // set text of vertical labels
        for (s, v) in zip(strs, [lYellow, lRed, lBlue]) {
            v.text = s
        }
        
        [container, greenView, normalLabel, lYellow, lRed, lBlue].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        // add greenView to the container
        container.addSubview(greenView)
        
        // add container to self's view
        view.addSubview(container)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain container Top and CenterX
            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            container.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            // comment next line to allow container subviews to set the height
            container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 260.0),
            
            // comment next line to allow container subviews to set the width
            container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),
            
            // green view at Top, stretched full width
            greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain normal label in green view
            //  with 8-pts "padding" on all 4 sides
            normalLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            normalLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            normalLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            normalLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
        ])
    }
    
}
```

The first example - `SubviewsExampleVC` - adds each as a subview, and then we add constraints between the views:

```
class SubviewsExampleVC: BaseVC {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // add vertical labels to the container
        [lYellow, lRed, lBlue].forEach { v in
            container.addSubview(v)
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // yellow label constrained to Bottom of green view
            lYellow.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            // Leading to container Leading
            lYellow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // red label constrained to Bottom of green view
            lRed.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            // Leading to yellow label Trailing
            lRed.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lYellow.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // blue label constrained to Bottom of green view
            lBlue.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            // Leading to red label Trailing
            lBlue.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lRed.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // if we want the labels to fill the container width
            //  blue label Trailing constrained to container Trailing
            lBlue.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // using constraints to set the vertical label heights
            lYellow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 132.0),
            lRed.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lYellow.heightAnchor),
            lBlue.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lYellow.heightAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // as always, we need to control which view(s)
        //  hug their content

        // so, for example, if we want the Yellow label to "stretch" horizontally
        lRed.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        lBlue.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        
        // or, for example, if we want the Red label to "stretch" horizontally
        //lYellow.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        //lBlue.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

    }

}
```

The second example = `StackviewExampleVC` - adds each as an arranged subview of a `UIStackView`:

```
class StackviewExampleVC: BaseVC {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // horizontal stack view
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        
        // add vertical labels to the stack view
        [lYellow, lRed, lBlue].forEach { v in
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // add stack view to container
        container.addSubview(stackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain stack view Top to green view Bottom
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // Leading / Trailing to container Leading / Trailing
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // stack view height
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 132.0),
            
        ])

        // as always, we need to control which view(s)
        //  hug their content
        // so, for example, if we want the Yellow label to "stretch" horizontally
        lRed.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        lBlue.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        
        // or, for example, if we want the Red label to "stretch" horizontally
        //lYellow.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        //lBlue.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        
    }
    
}
```

Both examples produce this output:

[image]

Please note: this is ***Example Code Only*** - it is not intended to be, nor should it be considered to be, ***Production Ready***

Comment: Thank you very much! Brilliant! Works out of the box! This is a much cleaner solution than I was hoping for! :)